# Incremental or Gradual?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, legalese

I would like to describe a process that is done gradually/incrementally, i.e., things do not change all at once - they change slowly.

In particular, I would like to describe a [land reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_reform) in which lands are taken from the wealthy and given to the poor, but this is not done all at once, rather it is done gradually/incrementally.

What is the correct term to use? "Gradual"? "Incremental"? Something else?

Comment: stealthily, perchance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are nearly synonymous but there are subtle differences.

**Incremental** highlights that the change was made in identifiable steps.

**Gradual** puts focus on the overall pace of change, which may by incremental or continuously slow.

> Venezuela bagan incremental land reform in 1998 which led to a gradual reduction in productivity and increase in food imports.

Comment: Interesting that you include "incremental" in your definition of gradual. I kind of consider the two to be opposites. An incremental change would be a change applied in steps, and a gradual change would be a change that happens uniformly over time.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama I think boatseller is quite right - in the formal register 'gradual' may imply *either* continuous change *or* discrete steps. The word *gradual* in fact derives from the Latin for *step*, and *gradual* is the adjective employed in speaking of different *grades* or *degrees'*. In colloquial use, on the other hand, *gradual* means neither of these; it just means *slow*.

Comment: I have the feeling that "gradual" remains silent as to whether whatever is gradual occurred uniformly or in steps.

Comment: Or that the increments, if any, are irrelevant.